# Phonegap Application Loader No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'icon.png'

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap, application-loader, phonegap-cli

I have recently started to run into an issue with my cordova/phonegap project that is causing Apple's Application Loader to blow up when uploading an ipa file.

Log from Application Loader:

```
"Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'icon.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-25.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-40.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22-2x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-50.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-57.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29-2x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22-3x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-72.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-25-3x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-76.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-80.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29-3x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-50-2x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60-2x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-76-2x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-83.5-2x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60-3x.png'"
ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.
 (1102)
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Success = false
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'icon.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-25.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-40.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22-2x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-50.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-57.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29-2x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22-3x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-72.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-25-3x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-76.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-80.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29-3x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-50-2x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60-2x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-76-2x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-83.5-2x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60-3x.png'"
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> DBG-X: The error code is: 1102
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main>  INFO: Done performing authentication.
[2017-12-12 11:56:38 EST] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1




Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/f6/6phqj0c95530gg9h8fwhqj1m0000gn/T/791FAC49-EA20-41B8-AEED-07A9016200BD/885130635.itmsp - Error Messages:
        description length:259720
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'icon.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-25.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-40.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22-2x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-50.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-57.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29-2x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-22-3x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-72.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-25-3x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-76.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-80.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-29-3x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-50-2x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60-2x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-76-2x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-83.5-2x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles': 'res/icon/ios/icon-60-3x.png'"
        ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
        ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
        ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
```

Config.xml file looks like such:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.app" version="1.4.12" versionCode="14112" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <content src="https://app.myapp.com/pg?app=com.myapp.app&amp;version=1.4.12" />
    <name>APP NAME</name>
    <description>
    LOREM IPSUM BLAH BLAH BLAH
  </description>
    <author email="zackherbert@gmail.com" href="http://MYAPP.com">
    MYCOMPANY, LLC
  </author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
    <preference name="pgb-builder-version" value="1" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="500" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
        <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
        <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
        <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustNothing" />
        <icon src="icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
        <icon qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
        <icon qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" />
        <splash src="splash.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-ldpi/screen.9.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-mdpi/screen.9.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-hdpi/screen.9.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xhdpi/screen.9.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xxhdpi/screen.9.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/screen.9.png" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
        <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
        <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
        <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
        <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
        <icon height="22" src="res/icon/ios/icon-22.png" width="22" />
        <icon height="25" src="res/icon/ios/icon-25.png" width="25" />
        <icon height="29" src="res/icon/ios/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="40" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="44" src="res/icon/ios/icon-22-2x.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="58" src="res/icon/ios/icon-29-2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="60" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="66" src="res/icon/ios/icon-22-3x.png" width="66" />
        <icon height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="75" src="res/icon/ios/icon-25-3x.png" width="75" />
        <icon height="76" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="80" src="res/icon/ios/icon-80.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="87" src="res/icon/ios/icon-29-3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="100" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="152" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5-2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="180" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />
        <splash height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1242" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h-2x.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1334" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h-2x.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="1536" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2208" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h-2x.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.0.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller" spec="^1.5.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="^2.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^1.10.6">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="11149707591" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="bidwrangler-opentok-plugin" spec="^1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.4" />
</widget>
```

Any insight on to why this is occurring all of the sudden would be appreciated. If more information is desired please feel free to ask.

Comment: Same problem here, started happening yesterday too

Comment: Guys I'm having the same issue. 1) downgrade your version of xcode from 9 to 8 because 9 is in beta and nobody is able to compile (check one post https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87862)    2) Re-create all your icons. I'm using right now makeappicon.com

Comment: Check this post: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2424645

Answer (score 0):

In order for me to get this problem to stop happening I upgrade to the latest xcode, rebuilt my coco-pods, and updated:

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />` to `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />`